# Only keep numbers in descending order by scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to write a function that just keeps the descending order numbers and gets rid of ascending ones.

For example:
`(descending '(6 5 3 1 2 8))`
should give me `(6 5 3 1)`.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `notAsc`? Did you mean `descending`?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the function properly? Is that a typo in your call with the apostrophe?

Comment: I modified the function to descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is the result of consing an object onto a list. Or an empty list.

What is consing? It is a built-in operation.

```
(define (plain-cons x xs)
  (cond
    ((null? xs) (list x))
    (else (cons x xs))))    ; using the built-in
```

A descending list is the result of *descend*-consing an object onto a *descending* list. Or an empty list.

What is a *descend*-consing? It is a consing such that the resulting list is also descending:

```
; (descend-cons 3 '())      -> (list 3)
; (descend-cons 8 '(7 3))   -> (cons 8 '(7 3))
; (descend-cons 5 '(8 7 3)) -> (descend-cons 5 '(7 3))

(define (descend-cons x xs)
  (cond
    ((null? xs) (list x))
    (else
       (let ((a (car xs)))
         (cond
           ((>= x a)      ; { 8 '(7 3)) } -> '(8 7 3)
              .... )
           (else          ; { 5 '(8 7 3)) } -> { 5 '(7 3) }
             (.... x 
                   (cdr xs))))))))
```

Armed with this, the task is easy. We'll write the function `descending` which turns a list into a descending list, simply as

```
; (descending '())           ->  '()
; (descending '(x y z ...))  ->  (descend-cons x (..... '(y z ...)))

(define (descending lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) lst)
    (else
      (let ((x (car lst))
            (xs (cdr lst)))
        (...... x
                (...... xs))))))
```

What is the second argument expected by `descend-cons`? It must be a *descending* list.

*Can* we create a descending list, from the list `'(y z ...)`? What function,  that we have in our arsenal, would do  this for us?

Comment: Nice solution, but why `cond` when there is only two terms and no need for at least one  `begin`?

Comment: @Sylwester I don't know, for uniformity maybe? I'm focusing on correctness first, here. I.e.,  on *problem-solving* approach.

Comment: Do u know what’s problem my program has?

Comment: @flower for (5 8 3) your approach will produce (8 3) but the correct answer is (5 3). Can you complete the code in my answer? It will become clear to you then. Don't rush it, read it slowly, make sure you understand each bit before moving on to the next. You are welcome to ask for clarifications if need be.